# Java function that throws RuntimeException

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm looking at some code and it's confusing me as I find it strange how a function's purpose is just to throw an error, although I'm sure there are reasons where it is helpful (at least that is what I think it's doing). My understanding of it is that if the arguments are of type `String` are passed into the function `putExtra` then a `RuntimeExeption` is thrown. Is my understanding correct? Below is the code,

```
@RecentlyNonNull
public Intent putExtra(String name, String value) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
}

public static final String ACTION_ID = "ACTION_ID";
Intent actionIntent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
actionIntent.putExtra(Constants.ACTION_ID, userId); //Where userId is also a string
```

If my understanding is correct what would be the reason behind this? Wouldn't an error be thrown automatically if any one of the arguments to the `putExtra` function is not of type `String`?

Comment: Is it related to android, right?

Comment: It looks like that function is a stub (effectively declared but doesn't do anything), and that exception is a warning telling uses to not use it. My best bet is that once it's been implemented, it will no longer throw that warning. Because of the annotation, I also bet it returned null until recently, and now it throws that exception instead.

Comment: @A. Wolf, yes that is correct

Comment: Sometimes APIs add such methods to preserve backward-compatible while making it clear that such methods have to be overridden in subclasses.

Comment: What's your purpose? Create a new activity and pass the intent? The method putExtra has been created by you?

Comment: Any chance you're using the IDE to look at the implementation of some platform class? That is, this is part of the Android framework or libraries, and not part of your own project? Often the IDE will put something like that in rather than the real code.

Comment: @A. Wolf, I didn't write the code, there is additional functionality that I am to implement and as I'm tracing the value of a variable I encountered the ```putExtra``` function

Comment: Ok, what is the additional functionality? Open a new activity? We need more context to give you a good answer.

Comment: It can't be called by passing anything but String. So its intention is to be not called and it warns by throwing runtime exception. It needs to be overridden

Comment: Please, add the code of the method which you are writing to help us understand.

Comment: Wait, what is Constants.ACTION_ID? You declared ACTION_ID before, but is it in a different class?

Comment: @ Salim, Ben P and ernest_k, thanks for the input. That makes more sense to me now.

Comment: Why is there no stack-trace of the `RuntimeException` provided? This could be anything.

Comment: @Salim this is not true; of course one can pass various other types, because `Intent` has getters and setters for extras of various types.

Answer (score 2):

These are just fake implementations that only exist for the Java compiler to know what APIs exist.  The actual implementations are on the device.  For instance, the implementation of `Intent` can be found [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/Intent.java#9204).

Answer (score 0):

This `RuntimeExeption` might have a whole other reason (please add the stack-trace). And even when looking at the method signatures, it's not always `String value`. The first argument must be `String`, because it is the name - while the second one argument is for the value and can have various types (not any type). See [work with breakpoints](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#breakPoints), which might rather explain why it crashes.